# Parsing text to object with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using an API which returns text in the following format:

```
#start
#p 12345 foo
#p 12346 bar
#end
#start
#p 12345 foo2
#p 12346 bar2
#end
```

My parsing function:

```
function parseApiResponse(data) {

    var results = [], match, obj;

    while (match = CST.REGEX.POST.exec(/(#start)|(#end)|#p\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/ig)) {

        if (match[1]) {           // #start
            obj = {};

        } else if (match[2]) {    // #end
            results.push(obj);
            obj = null;           // prevent accidental reuse 
                                  // if input is malformed

        } else {                  // #p something something
            obj[match[3]] = match[4];
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

This will give me a list of objects which looks something like this:

```
[{ '12345': 'foo', '12346': 'bar'}, /* etc... */]
```

However, if a line is formatted like this

```
#start
#p 12345
#p 12346 bar
#end
```

The line would actually be `#p 12345\n` and my `match[4]` would contain the next row's `#p`.

How do I adjust the pattern to adapt to this?

Comment: On your fourth match, you're not allowing white space with `\S+`. Maybe that will give you a hint.

Comment: @tgies I just added it since I saw it on http://www.regexr.com/ while testing

Comment: @Johan never mind, that was a stupid question, I confused myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have one `#start`, `#end`, or `#p` element per line, you can make your regex aware of this and add an additional non-capturing group to indicate that the last `\s+(\S+)` in a line is optional:

`/(#start)|(#end)|#p\s+(\S+)(?:\s+(\S+))?$/igm`

`(?: )` is saying "treat this as a group, but don't capture the pattern it matches" (so it won't create an element in `match`). The `?` that follows that group means "this group is optional and may or may not match anything in the pattern". The `$` right after that, in conjunction with the `m` flag, matches the end of the line.

You can also avoid the `(?: )` trickery by using * instead of + quantifiers, meaning "match zero or more times": change `\s+(\S+)` to `\s*(\S*)`. This has the side effect that the space between the number and the data that follows it is now optional.

I would rewrite the regex and refactor the code a bit as follows:

```
while (match = CST.REGEX.POST.exec(/^#(start|end|p)(?:\s+(\d+)(?:[^\S\r\n]+([^\r\n]+))?)?$/igm)) {
  switch (match[1]) {
    case 'start':
      obj = {};
      break;
    case 'end':
      results.push(obj);
      obj = null;
      break;
    case 'p':
      obj[match[2]] = match[3];
      break;
  }
}
```

I like capturing `start`, `end`, or `p` in the one capture group so I can use it in a `switch` statement. The version of the regex I use here is a little more discriminating (expects the token that follows `#p` to be numeric) and a little more forgiving (allows the last token on a `#p` line to contain any non-linebreak whitespace, e.g. `#p 1138 this is only a test`).

Comment: Great, thanks! Final question: How do I allow the last group to contain spaces and digits e.g. `#p 12345 foo` can also be `#p 12345 foo bar 1`, where `foo bar 1` would be the last group. Too tricky perhaps?

Comment: That's doable. You need to change the last optional noncapturing group to `(?:[^\S\r\n]+([^\r\n]+))?)`. That means "anything that's *not not* whitespace and not a linebreak (= any space other than linebreaks) any number of times, followed by any character other than a linebreak any number of times." I'm editing the answer in a moment.